Как можно максимально оптимизировать запрос?
У меня есть следующий код:

Он группирует юзеров по user_id, role_id, date_trunc('day', update)
Из каждой группы берет последнию запись по update
Далее эти последние записи дополнительно группирует по user_id, role_id, currency и берет так  же последнюю запись из группы по
update
Далее эти записи финально группирует по currency и суммирует поле
amount

Как можно максимально оптимизировать этот запрос т.к. в данный момент на большой выборке он выполняется долго ?
WITH rankedUsers AS (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, role_id, date_trunc('day', update) ORDER BY update DESC) AS rank
    FROM users
    WHERE 
        AND update < '2024-02-01 00:00:00'
),
lastRankedUsers AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM rankedUsers 
    WHERE rank = 1
),
filteredUsers AS (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, role_id, currency ORDER BY update DESC) AS filteredRank
    FROM lastRankedUsers
),
lastFilteredUsers AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM filteredUsers 
    WHERE filteredRank = 1
)
SELECT 
    currency,
    SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM lastFilteredUsers 
GROUP BY currency;

